# Detect Page Layout using Machine Learning

Tags: modeling

i try to make An application that used to tag page something like HTML Pages

is there is a way using  ML to detect and identify the layout of the page

Headers , tables , Footer

or it should only using AI Algorithms

can any one help me in this point

best reagrds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Faster RCNN referring to this Post 
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

and it worked fine with me also i tried some other algorithm to enhance the result like RLSA you can refer to this also

https://pypi.org/project/pythonRLSA/

i couldn't copy a sample of my output is it relative to my business work  but result is very optimistic

hope help you

Comment: Using Deep Learning